# How to select account each login by facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication

When I logged in with facebook for the first time, it was fine.
I then log in again, it will automatically retrieve the account I logged in last time. How does it always allow me to select an account every time I log in (like google 'select_account').
and I cannot log in with any other facebook account, other than logout from facebook.com, then return to my website.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: _“other than logout from facebook.com, then return to my website”_ - well, that’s what you will have to do then. Facebook does not have an explicit “user switching” implementation, because according to their terms, any person is allowed to have only one personal account in the first place - so there should not be much necessity for that kind of account switching to begin with.